# MIDI Events Note ON, ON, OFF. How to interpret?

Tags: midi

I found a MIDI file which I don't know how to interpret, it starts something like this:

```
Tick: 384
NOTE ON
Channel: 1
Velocity: 127
Pitch: 53

Tick: 672
NOTE ON
Channel: 1
Velocity: 127
Pitch: 53

Tick: 768
NOTE OFF
Channel: 1
Velocity: 85
Pitch: 53
```

I noticed at least 1 MIDI player seem to take the middle ON and interpret it as a NOTE OFF then NOTE ON at same tick, is that correct behavior? I suspect it is but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MIDI spec:

> ASSIGNMENT OF NOTE ON/OFF COMMANDS
>
> If an instrument receives two or more Note On messages with the same key number and MIDI channel, it must make a determination of how to handle the additional Note Ons. It is up to the receiver as to whether the same voice or another voice will be sounded, or if the messages will be ignored. The transmitter, however, must send a corresponding Note Off message for every Note On sent. If the transmitter were to send only one Note Off message, and if the receiver in fact assigned the two Note On messages to different voices, then one note would linger. Since there is no harm or negative side effect in sending redundant Note Off messages this is the recommended practice.
>
> VOICE ASSIGNMENT IN POLY MODE
>
> In Poly mode there are no particular rules which define how to assign voices when more than one Note On message is received and recognized. If more Note On messages are transmitted than the receiver is capable of playing, the receiver is free to use any method of dealing with this "overflow" situation (such as first vs. last note priority). The priority of voice assignments may follow the order in which Note On messages are received, the receiver's own keyboard control logic, or some other scheme.
> When a transmitter sends Note On and Off information to a receiving keyboard which is also being played, it is important for the receiver to distinguish the source of Note On/Off information. For example, a Note Off received from MIDI should not turn off a note that is being played on the receiver's own keyboard. Conversely, releasing a key on the receiver's own keyboard should not turn off a note being received from MIDI.

So I suppose every method is appropriate.